# Failure to Jack-in with spacemacs

Tags: clojure, spacemacs, cider

I can run a repll and connect but when I try to Jack in I get the following error (shown in debug) - I am using emacs 26.1 on Mojave. I tried reinstalling spacemacs and updating clojure

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not start nREPL server:
>   /usr/local/bin/lein: line 72: basename: command no$   signal(error
>   ("Could not start nREPL server: /usr/local/bin/lein: line 72:
>   basename: command not found\n/usr/local/b$   error("Could not start
>   nREPL server: %s" "/usr/local/bin/lein: line 72: basename: command not
>   found\n/usr/local/bin/$   nrepl-server-sentinel(# "exited abnormally with code 127\n")

Comment: do you have `basename` command in your path? for me, it is in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: Thank I checked and I do have basename in my path and I even tried copying it to /usr/local/bin/ where lien is nothing work. Lein repl from the command line works fine.

Comment: It may not be available in spacemacs path then. Are you in `develop` branch of Spacemacs? Then you may have to check your `PATH` variable in spacemacs.env file

Comment: Spacemacs.env Looks OK to me - I am in Development and I start from the terminal: PATH=/Users/tmb/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/tmb/.pyenv/bin:/Users/tmb/.npm-packages\
/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/bin/packer:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/\
9.3/bin:/Users/tmb/lib/vsts-cli/bin